# Entertainment Discombobulation

Tags: knowledge, video-games

In the very near future, Bob Mancave (the one who lives on Krypton street next to the Jawa shop) was presumed dead after having been missing for over a week. He was said to be found in his mancave, under a mountain of pizza crusts and a few thousand custom titled video game boxes (presumely crushed as the shelf which probably held the games was found collapsed next to it).

Detective Hubert Clueless, tasked with inspecting the scene barely skimmed the top of the video game pile (supposedly hiding the corpse), before declaring with omnipotence:

"Bob isn't dead you buffoons, there is no corpse here, he just probably went to buy a new game."

"But Detective, he's been gone for over a week!"

To which the Detective answered:
"Here, take a look at these titles, you can probably guess what game he went to buy:"

- Future Breeze
- Unending Task
- Shielded Heart
- Velocity Urge
- Era Fighters
- Crimson Band
- Pumpkin Chest
- Robot Attack
- Networked Nightfall
- Satan Tears
- Hit-man Code

"They just spell it right out! Figure it out yet? Now go get me some mountain dew."

What game is Bob out to buy?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The existing games are:

- Future Breeze - *Morrowind*
- Unending Task - *Everquest*
- Shielded Heart - *Armored Core*
- Velocity Urge - *Need for Speed*
- Era Fighters - *Dynasty Warriors*
- Crimson Band - *Red Faction*
- Pumpkin Chest - *Orange Box*
- Robot Attack - *Mech War*
- Networked Nightfall - *EVE Online*
- Satan Tears - *Devil May Cry*
- Hit-man Code - *Assassin's Creed*

The first letter of each game title spell out ME ANDROMEDA, so the game he has gone out to buy (and will be out for a while, it's not releasing until late next year), is *Mass Effect : Andromeda*.

Full credits go to @deusovi, @Going hamateur, @Mekalikot, @GentlePurpleRain, and particularly @fodder.

Comment: morrow wind for future breeze

Comment: @Goinghamateur I thought of that, but Afterwind seemed like a better fit. Besides, a lot of the others are franchises rather than individual games, so Morrowind would be Elder Scrolls.

Comment: hmmm, I can see that the first letters of the games can spell out word or set of words.AE AND etc.. 

is that the clue for "They just spell it right out! Figure it out yet? Now go get me some mountain dew"

Comment: Assuming it's Morrowind, it could be M.E. Andromeda (Mass Effect: Andromeda). I'm not sure what Robot Attack and Networked Nightfall are, but they'd have to start with M and E, respectively.

Comment: @Fodder Robot Attack could be Mech War

Comment: Robot Attack was intended to be MechAssault - Morrowind was the only one not a franchise but I didnt think it would be a problem (never heard of afterwind or anything that would've fit. + its too awesome to not put on the list imo :P )

Comment: @Spacemonkey Heh, couldn't agree more.